# R Counting all times as 00:00:00 in ggplot bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, time, bar-chart

I am trying to run a bar graph using a continuous x variable (time) to see what times bikes have the most usage.

There is roughly 400000 data points but when I run above it counts every single start_time as 00:00:00.

How do I get this to actually plot the different times on the graph?

```
bike_202204 %>% 
  filter(start_time != 00:00:00) %>% 
  ggplot(data = subset(bike_202204, !is.na(start_time)),
         mapping = aes(x = start_time))+
  geom_bar()
```

[bar graph that is output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQ73y.png)

The str() function shows `start_time = col_time(format = "")`.

Comment: Can you share a sample of your data using `dput()`? Also, the data you are piping into the function is not being used in the ggplot. You should try replacing the `ggplot` call with `ggplot(data = subset(., !is.na(start_time)), mapping = aes(x = start_time))`

Comment: Another note - bar graphs are used for a discrete variable. You should either use `factor(start_time)` to turn `start_time` into a discrete variable, or the better option is to use a histogram with `geom_histogram` :)